# Charlock_holmes 0.7.6 install errors

Tags: windows, rubygems

i have been going round in circles , im trying to install charlock holmes 0.7.6 on a windows 10 pc , i have ubuntu installed and everything else seams to be fine .
i would have to say , i am very new at this :-(
i need it to run in the cmd rather than the linux prompt .
i have tried varous published fixes with no luck .
"gem install Charlock_holmes -v 0.7.6" gives me this result

```
C:\GSDev\grubstub>gem build charlock_holmes-0.7.6.gem
Invalid gemspec in [charlock_holmes-0.7.6.gem]: undefined local variable or method `metadata' for Gem::Specification:Class
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
C:\GSDev\grubstub>gem install --local charlock_holmes-0.7.6.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes-0.7.6.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/ext/charlock_holmes
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r ./siteconf20220305-6628-1mj0usf.rb extconf.rb
checking for -licui18n... no
which: no brew in (/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Ruby24-x64/bin:/c/Users/GStub/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/GStub/.dotnet/tools)
checking for -licui18n... no
***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-icu-dir
        --without-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include
        --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --with-icu-lib
        --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/lib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
  C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/mkmf.log
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/charlock_holmes-0.7.6/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the ICU libraries are installed:

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-icu icu-devel icu
```

Then you can install the gem with this:

```
gem install --local charlock_holmes-0.7.6.gem -- --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
```

or get the latest version:

```
gem install charlock_holmes -- --with-icui18nlib=icuin --with-icudatalib=icudt
```

**EDIT:** You are using Ruby 2.4 which was released in 2016. That means that the MSYS64 installation bundled with RubyInstaller - which I assume you used - is quite outdated itself. (Some background: [What do these RubyInstaller 2.4 components do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229081/what-do-these-rubyinstaller-2-4-components-do))

That's why you get errors regarding outdated certificates and outdated mirror lists.

Unfortunately there is no easy workaround, because in order to get fresh certificates you need to download a package, which doesn't work, because the current certificates are outdated...

You have several options here:

1. Try to repair the MSYS with the workarounds found on the web (search for *MSYS64 SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired error*) (**Potentially time consuming, Linux knowledge helps**)
2. Use a newer Ruby version from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. Version 2.7 would be a conservative choice coming from Ruby 2.4. Version 3.0 and 3.1 have some breaking changes. (**Best choice if you actually can use a newer Ruby**)
3. Re-Install MSYS64 (**I previously did this after solution #1 didn't work for me**), but don't just use the original Ruby installer. Instead download the current installer from https://www.msys2.org/ and install to the same directory as current. (Perhaps rename the original directory first to get a 100% clean installation) 

   Then run `ridk install` to register the MSYS64 installation with Ruby.

Comment: hi Daniel , thank you for getting back to me , i got all excited to finally get this working , then i got this result :-(

Comment: >ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-icu icu-devel icu
warning: icu-60.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) icu-60.2-1  icu-devel-60.2-1  mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-61.1-1

Total Download Size:    25.61 MiB
Total Installed Size:  140.94 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      111.35 MiB

Comment: : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'icu-devel-60.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'icu-devel-60.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.yandex.ru : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

Comment: i have also tried in admin cmd prompt :-( , still no joy

Comment: :: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-61.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from repo.msys2.org : SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-61.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-61.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw-w64-x86_64-icu-61.1-1-any.pkg.tar.xz' from

Comment: Yeah, these errors stem from an outdated MSYS64 installation. Added some pointers to the answer.